# Frobenius endomorphism of Abelian varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Let $A$ be an abelian variety over $\mathbb{F}_q$ with $q=p^n$, such that all of it's endomorphisms are defined over $\mathbb{F}_q$. Then $End(A)\otimes \mathbb{Q}$ is of Albert type (IV) with center $L$ a CM-field. Let $T_p(A)$ be it's p-divisible group. Due to the Tate-conjecture $End(A)\otimes \mathbb{Z}_p\xrightarrow{\sim} End(T_p(A))$ are isomorphic. But on one hand the Frobenius endomorphism $\pi_A$ of $A$ is in $L$ and on the other hand given the description of $End(T_p(A)) \otimes \mathbb{Q}_p$ from Dieudonne theory, $\pi_{A}$ can not be central in $End(T_p(A)) \otimes \mathbb{Q}_p$. So what am I missing here?

Comment: Morphisms of $p$-divisible groups commute with Frobenius.

Comment: Suppose we have the minimal p-Divisible group $H_{m,n}$ in the sense of Oort. Then $End(H_{m,n})$ is a noncommutative local ring $W(\mathbb{F}_{p^{n+m}})[\pi]$ where $\pi = F^{x}V^{y}$ with $my+nx=1$. Then the Frobenius $F$ is not in the center of $End(H_{m,n})$. Or is $F$ not the Frobenius automorphism in this case?

Comment: You have to be careful to use the $q$-Frobenius on both sides I think! For example it is not true that $\operatorname{End}_{A_{\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p}} \otimes \mathbb{Z}_p \simeq \operatorname{End}({A_{\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p}}[p^{\infty}])$.

Comment: The endomorphism ring of your minimal $p$-divisible group $X$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ is actually commutative and I suspect that $F^n$ will be in the center of the endomorphism ring of $X_{\mathbb{F}_{p^n}}$.

Comment: Over $\mathbb{F}_p$ it is, but then the field is not sufficiently large. But I figured I was mixing the iterated Frobenius and base-change with $\sigma^n$. Thanks!